# -Woverflow catn cout value

Tags: c++, overflow

I just started programming and I wrote the following code, but for some reason, it doesn't show the correct value even though I am almost sure that I way overkilled the value type.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned long long int imin = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::min(); // minimum value
    unsigned long long int imax = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max(); // maximum value

    std::cout << imin << " " << imax << std::endl;

    unsigned long long int a;
    a = 45*44*43*42*41*40;
    std::cout << "die wahrscheinlichkeit ist: 1:"  << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get this:

> 0 18446744073709551615
>   die wahrscheinlichkeit ist: 1:1569475904
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

and this warning:

> Warnung: Ganzzahlüberlauf in Ausdruck [-Woverflow]
>        a = 45*44*43*42*41*40;

Translated, it means whole number overflow in the expression (or something like that).

When I use a normal calculator, I get this 5864443200.

I am using C++14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is indeed that you have an overflow in you normal int numbers. You declarations are fine except in the calculation. The numbers 40, 41, 42, 43, 44 and 45 are normal integers with their respective length. They get multiplied as normal integers and when the number get to big the overflow happens. After the calculation is complete (and the overflow already happened) the numbers get transformed to the unsigned long long int.

So make the numbers also of the type  **long long unsigned** with the LLU suffix:

```
a = 45LLU * 44LLU * 43LLU * 42LLU * 41LLU * 40LLU;
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: but does it mean that each time I do such operations it automatically creates hidden variables.

Comment: No it doesn't create a variable due to the multiplication but due to the hard coded numbers. Remember that nothing can come from nowhere, so these hard coded numbers need to live somewhere in memory, in a certain format. Please mark the answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: Certainly with floats and ints it is important to keep this in mind. For better understanding run cout <<  1/2; and cout << 1.0/2; one will give the correct answer in doubles, the other an answer in integers.